# How can I check a PHP script for structure errors?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a lot of ajax that calls php files to do tasks, like write things to the server. I use load calls so anything the php echoes when it gets into trouble comes back to me.  But if I've done something really dumb, like leave off a ")",  the PHP doesn't even start and all I get is a cryptic

```
        POST http://www.mysite.com/publishPage.php 500 Internal Server Error
```

Isn't there something that will tell me "missing ) at line 119" ?

I've placed

```
               ini_set('display_errors', 1);
               error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of the PHP scripts but that doesn't seem to be helping me here.

Thanks

Comment: Those errors are probably in your server logs, and instead of displaying them to your users, they are getting logged and the server is returning a 500.

Comment: From the command line, you can run `php -l <filename>` to check a file for syntax errors (you can also run `php <filename>` to actually run it, to see what the output is.)

Comment: @andrewsi:  What command line are you referring to?

Comment: It's the one you get when you SSH onto the server; or if you run `cmd` on a Windows computer. I'm somewhat old school, and much more comfortable with a text prompt than with a fancy GUI editor.

Comment: Got it!  I was able to SSH into my server with putty and do the php -l badfile.php  to see the error. I also located the server error logs, at /var/www/httpd-logs, which showed the same information. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors can not be "checked" if you missed the code, will have to fix before trying to run it.

If you have a syntax error in java, the code will not be compiled. php is not compiled, then this is the solution